# How to download a text typed into the codepath using linux tools?

Tags: html, linux, wget

I have a link to the online text editor coderpath: `https://coderpad.io/MY_ID`:

[image]

Users with access to the link can type the text there and the text one user types will become visible to all users on the network (similar to Google Docs).

I would like to periodically download the latest text that is typed there using the linux shell, but a simple command

```
wget "https://coderpad.io/MY_ID" -O text.txt
```

downloads some HTML file that **does not** contain the text I typed.

Since my browser displays the text on my screen, I assume that the browser has downloaded it from the web and thus there should be a way to download it again and save it into my own text file. **How**?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `wget "https://coderpad.io/MY_ID" -O text.txt` command does not download the code you typed into the coderpad is because the command is actually downloading a different content depicted in the image below:

[image]

Delete the **cookies** of your current session or type `https://coderpad.io/MY_ID` into a new browser and you will also see this image rather than the expected code.

Once you enter the requested name into the page and click `Go`, a few steps later the browser stores new **cookies** for this webpage. The main cookie related to this question is:

```
Cookie name             | Cokie value example | Explanation
pad_7JJWMNDA_username   | Grace Hopper        | Name entered into the bar
```

For the next requests to refresh the page, the browser will send an HTTP request to the website with **this cookie embedded**. By examining the cookie value, the server will decide to return the expected code rather than the "Enter your name" request.

In theory, adding appropriate cookie values as extra arguments to the `wget` command should make the server return the expected code. I did not succeed to download the code this way, because of the multiple hidden requests and responses exchanged between the browser and the server. Those hidden requests complicate the whole download procedure.

However, a workaround that works for me is the following:

1. Download auto HAR extension from `https://github.com/Aloisius/autohar`. HAR is basically the log of your browser tab activity with content included.
2. Change `max_entries: 100` to `max_entries: 1` in all files. This tells to download the HAR after each page refresh (rather than after 100 page refreshes).
3. Install this modified extension into the `Chrome` browser.
4. Open the new tab and **open developer tools for that tab** by clicking CTRL + SHIFT + I.
5. Now whenever you refresh the page in this particular tab, HAR file will be downloaded to your `~/Downloads` folder.
6. That HAR file will contain the custom code of interest. You can then use `grep`
   to extract only the code of interest and filter out the rest of the log.